# Facebook publish_actions deprecated

Tags: xcode, facebook

What can I do to use as an alternative to publish_actions? I have a photo app that lets users share their photos to their profile. Currently it uses logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] and then shares the files through FBSDKSharePhoto. But after August 1 this will be removed. Any thoughts? This is my current code but soon it won't work.

```
-(IBAction)loginToFacebook:(id)sender
{
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;

    [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                    fromViewController:self
                               handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Process error");

                                   } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                       NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                                       nonpressTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeout) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
                                   } else {
                                       NSLog(@"Logged in");

                                       [self shareSegmentWithFacebookComposer];
                                   }

                               }];
}

- (void)shareBoothOnFacebook {
NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data6 = [defaults2 objectForKey:@"layoutphoto"];
UIImage *myImage = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data6];


NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrSlidshowImg count]; i++) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i]];
        FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
        photo.image = image;
        photo.userGenerated = YES;
        [photos addObject:photo];


    }

 FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = [photos copy];
[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil];


}
}
```

Comment: Well unless they come up with something new in that regard by August, I think your only option might be to let your app users share links that have the photo set as thumbnail. (Will require a server-side component, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to switch to using Facebook's iOS sharing APIs which require that the Facebook Messenger app is installed.  See their [documentation on sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios).

You might also want to investigate the use of the [iOS share sheet](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/sharing-and-actions/) but that also requires the Facebook Messenger app to be installed to enable sharing to Facebook.